# How do I snapshot the database in the Kadena devnet?

Tags: kadena

I am using Kadena's [devnet](https://github.com/kadena-io/devnet) for integration testing. Unfortunately, every time I start up devnet it begins from scratch, with no history, and it takes a long time (more than an hour) to become usable. As [described in the README](https://github.com/kadena-io/devnet/tree/542ada1878bc182b5e94deaf8212a8bbcf8b155d#caveats):

> If you are starting from a fresh database, you may wish to wait for the block height of each chain to pass the latest feature fork for devnet. As of 2.15, this is a height of 165. It takes an hour or so to reach this from scratch.

This sounds like I can avoid my issue with long startup times by beginning from an already-populated database. The database is deleted every time `docker compose` is terminated, but the README states that [this can be avoided with a `devnet.yaml` file](https://github.com/kadena-io/devnet/tree/542ada1878bc182b5e94deaf8212a8bbcf8b155d#caveats):

> Node restarts without deleting the database can be performed by defining nodes in devnet.yaml that store the database on a named value or on the host.

However, there is no example `devnet.yaml` file in the devnet repository, and I don't know what I should write in this file to make snapshots appropriately. How do I snapshot the database using a `devnet.yaml` file so that I can restart devnet at a block height of at least 165?

Answer (score 1):

We're hoping to make the forks on devnet manually controlled rather than triggering them at fixed block heights. In the meantime, the database (by default) is located in the db-server-db Docker volume, and you can copy it out of there.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `docker compose down` your database will be reset, so I prefer to stop the docker with `docker compose stop`.

I haven't tried taking snapshots with `devnet.yaml`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).